# Summation of 1/k

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What is summation of 1/k where n ranges from 1 to n.
I need the general formula for the summation. 
I know the series tends to infinity when k tends to infinity . But upto n terms there must be a definite sum value. Correct ?

Comment: It has a definite value, but there is no closed-form formula for that definite value in terms of standard elementary functions.

Comment: are you sure.. ? 
Somewhere I remember seeing it as gamma + ln(n) where gamma is euler-mascheroni constant

Comment: That's an approximation, true in the limit. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37496/nitpicky-question-about-harmonic-series

Comment: @Adeetya The formula you are thinking of is $H_n=\gamma+\psi_0(n+1)$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1}
=\Psi\left(n + 1\right) - \Psi\left(1\right) = \gamma + \Psi\left(n + 1\right)
$$
$\Psi\left(z\right)$ and $\gamma$ are the
[Digamma Function and the Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) , respectively.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In terms of the Gamma Function $\Gamma(z)$: $\Psi(z) = {\rm d}\ln\Gamma(z)/{\rm d}z$.

Answer (score 0):

This partial sum defines the $n$-th "harmonic number". You can find lots of information on these numbers by looking up that term. But no simple and exact closed formula.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover if you want to compute with some easy steps the *$n$-th Harmonic Number*, there is a demonstration that asserts that  $H_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} = \ln(n) + \frac{1}{2n} + \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is, as said before, the *Euler-Mascheroni constant*.

Comment: You do not need to use TeX to get something like italics, you can use [markdown](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).